# Using javascript on a button action to autofill data in AdobeDC

Tags: javascript

I'm working in adobe dc and trying to create a button with the action to add predetermined values(autofill) into some of the form fields when it is pressed. The fields are labeled as vfdhzrequired, vfdhzactual, vfdhzrequired_1, vfdhzactual_1. I would like, upon the button press, to script the action to write the field values to N/A.

Simple, I'm sure, but I'm a simple guy.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Again, it was simple but I was struggling. This is a function inside a "button" in Adobe DC. The button is coded to allow, upon press, to apply the value of the field directdrivedata to all fields below.

this.getField("Fan Sheave  Shaft.0").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("MotorSheaveShaft.0").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("Belt Size  Number.0").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("C to C.0").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("Motor Sheave  Shaft.1").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("Fan Sheave  Shaft.1").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("Belt Size  Number.1").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

this.getField("C to C.1").value = this.getField("directdrivedata").value;

This worked great for me and got me started on some more difficult stuff. 
I'm excited!